# UISearchBar jumping out of position once tapped

Tags: ios, autolayout, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uisearchbardelegate

I am trying to display a `MySearchBar` (`UISearchBar` with added `UILabel` to display the title) as the `navigationItem`'s view:

```
// Make search bar autoresize and occupy maximum width
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds];
self.navigationItem.titleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:self.mySearchBar.view];
self.mySearchBar.view.frame = self.navigationItem.titleView.frame;
```

The search bar sits in place until it is tapped. After tapping, it moves down and it no longer occupies full width (around 16px are missing).

Before editing (how it should look):

[image: Before editing]

Editing began (BUG - after tapping the search bar grows in height to the default 56px and loses width):

[image: Editing began]

Editing ended (remains misplaced)

[image: Editing ended]

Here is the initialization code of `MySearchBar`. It consists of two main views, `titleView` wraps the `UILabel` with title and `searchBarWrapperView` wraps the `UISearchBar`:

```
-(id) init {
    // Initialize the two wrapping views
    UIView *titleView = [UIView new];
    self.searchBarWrapperView = [UIView new];

    // Resize UILabel to fit its content
    self.titleLabel = [UILabel new];
    self.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.titleLabel sizeToFit];

    self.searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.searchBarTextField = [self.searchBar valueForKey:@"searchField"];// This could be the text field that gets displaced???

    // Add two main subviews (wrappers)
    [self.view addSubview:titleView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchBarWrapperView];

    // Add title label and search bar to the subviews
    [titleView addSubview:self.titleLabel];
    [self.searchBarWrapperView addSubview:self.searchBar];

    // Disable auto constraints
    [titleView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.searchBarWrapperView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.titleLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    // Set constraints for title view
    [titleView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [titleView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [titleView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor].active = YES;
    [titleView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.titleLabel.bottomAnchor].active = YES;

    // Set constraints for title label
    [self.titleLabel.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:titleView.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.titleLabel.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:titleView.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.titleLabel.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:titleView.rightAnchor].active = YES;

    // Set constraints for search bar wrapper
    [self.searchBarWrapperView.heightAnchor constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToConstant:30].active = YES;// The search bar together with the title label should occupy the whole 44px height of the navigation bar
    [self.searchBarWrapperView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:titleView.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.searchBarWrapperView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.searchBarWrapperView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.searchBarWrapperView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor constant:16].active = YES;// Add space that is lost by setSearchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment

    // Configure autoresizing mask for UISearchBar
    [self.searchBar setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [self.searchBar setFrame:self.searchBarWrapperView.frame];

    //Remove left and right blank spaces around UISearchBar
    [self.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-8,0)];

    // Colors for debugging        
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    searchBarWrapperView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    self.searchBarTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used was to subclass the `UISearchBar` and the `UISearchController`. That way I can set the frame and control the search bar events.

`SearchBar.swift`:

```
import Foundation

class SearchBar : UISearchBar {

    var preferredFont:UIFont?
    var preferredTextColor:UIColor?

    init(frame: CGRect, font: UIFont, textColor: UIColor) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.frame = frame
        self.preferredFont = font
        self.preferredTextColor = textColor
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
}
```

`SearchController.swift`:

```
import Foundation

protocol SearchControllerDelegate {
    func didStartSearching()

    func didTapOnSearchButton()

    func didTapOnCancelButton()

    func didChangeSearchText(searchText: String)
}

class SearchController : UISearchController, UISearchBarDelegate, SearchControllerDelegate {

    var customSearchBar: SearchBar!
    var customDelegate: SearchControllerDelegate!

    init(searchResultsController: UIViewController!, searchBarFrame: CGRect, searchBarFont: UIFont, searchBarTextColor: UIColor, searchBarTintColor: UIColor) {
        super.init(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        configureSearchBar(frame: searchBarFrame, font: searchBarFont, textColor: searchBarTextColor, bgColor: searchBarTintColor)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    func configureSearchBar(frame: CGRect, font: UIFont, textColor: UIColor, bgColor: UIColor) {
        self.customSearchBar = SearchBar(frame: frame, font: font , textColor: textColor)

        self.customSearchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        self.customSearchBar.barTintColor = bgColor
        self.customSearchBar.tintColor = textColor
        self.customSearchBar.showsBookmarkButton = false
        self.customSearchBar.showsCancelButton = false

        self.customSearchBar.delegate = self
        self.customDelegate = self;

        let searchBarTextField:UITextField = self.customSearchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField

        searchBarTextField.font = font
        searchBarTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        searchBarTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        searchBarTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    }

    // UISearchBarDelegate

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        customDelegate.didStartSearching()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        customSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        customDelegate.didTapOnSearchButton()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        customSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        customDelegate.didTapOnCancelButton()
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        customDelegate.didChangeSearchText(searchText: searchText)
    }

    // SearchControllerDelegate

    func didStartSearching() {

    }

    func didTapOnSearchButton() {
        var searchText:String = ""

        if (self.customSearchBar.text != nil) {
            searchText = self.customSearchBar.text!
        }

        self.search(searchQuery: searchText)
    }

    func didTapOnCancelButton() {

    }

    func didChangeSearchText(searchText: String) {
        self.search(searchQuery: searchText)
    }

    // Search
    func search(searchQuery: String) {
        // Start searching
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! do you know by chance how to get the "Cancel" button to show itself with this?

Comment: Don’t know, moved to other project since.